# Sync data from couch DB to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, couchdb

In my application i am using couch db for the temporary storage for offline feature. For permanent storage i am using Mongodb in my application. Is it possible to sync data from couch db to Mongodb ?

Please suggest

Comment: Have you ever though of using [MiniMongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo) for temporary storage(Offline) ?

Comment: @AlexisCôté I don't know about MiniMongo. Is it possible to use instead of Couch DB

Comment: MiniMongo is like using PouchDB except for MongoDB. So I guess it would be better to use since it's as using MongoDB.